# Adding prepare statement results in warning

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create the best global select query using prepare statements, and everything is ok excepting the fact that I am getting a warning:

`Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement`

The unique global select function

```
function querysp($selectquery, $type_bind, $colval) {
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare($selectquery);
    $stmt->bind_param($type_bind,$colval);
    $stmt->execute();
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $colval);
    $arr = array();
    if ($stmt) {
        while ($result = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            array_push($arr, $result);
        }
    }
    return $arr;    
}
```

The example use:

```
$select = "SELECT * from advertising WHERE status = ?";
$status = 1;
$advertising = querysp($select, 'i', $status);
foreach ($advertising as $ad) {
    $banner[] = $ad['banner'];
    $bannercode[] = $ad['bannercode'];
    $location[] = $ad['location'];
    $status = $ad['status'];
}
```

What am I missing? Sorry did not get exactly prepare staments, checked also here at SO and on Google, but can't get to fix this.

EDIT 2

I have changed the select query because I changed the type of bind param from b (I thought it meant boolean) to i, but still getting the error.

EDIT 3 - current version -- still getting same error:

```
$select = "SELECT banner, bannercode, location, status from advertising WHERE status = ?";
$status = 1;
$advertising = querysp($select, 'i', $status);
foreach ($advertising as $ad) {
    $banner[] = $ad['banner'];
    $bannercode[] = $ad['bannercode'];
    $location[] = $ad['location'];
    $status = $ad['status'];
}
```

and the function

```
function querysp($selectquery, $type_bind, $colval) {
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare($selectquery);
    $stmt->bind_param($type_bind,$colval);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($result);
    $arr = array();
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $arr[] = $result;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: this means the ammount of `"?"` in your query does not match the ammount of variables you give it

Comment: odd, it should be only one value, there fore I am thinking on only one variable that I named it $status.

Comment: `$stmt->bind_param($type_bind,$colval);` In this line you are specifying two parameters, and as you only have 1 placeholder `?`, the code has two parameters for 1 placeholder. This produces the error you are seeing.

Comment: @Danieloplata Please reveiw the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) for `bind_param`. `bind_param` takes at the least two parameters, the parameter types as a string of characters and the parameters themselves.

Comment: @kpp ok sure, it's much appreciated, trying to build the perfect select/insert/delete/update functions and your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @War10ck Please refrain from spamming the link to the documentation. Binding data types for parameters is optional. Binding it in this way will cause the statement to ignore that the first variable is binding the data types and cause it to be the first real parameter.

Comment: @Adrian are you sure the error is referring to _this_ particular query?

Comment: @Danieloplata Two things I would like to note please: (1) adding a link to documentation is not spam. I don't appreciate that. (2) No where on that page does it say it is optional. It would be wrapped in square brackets if it were.

Comment: @DamienPirsy yes it is, I even got errors when changing some things.

Comment: @Adrian I am still working on it, but the editor is causing me to take some time :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took some while but here's my version of the prepared statements its a quite the wall but it pretty much captures most errors that can possibly be made. I tried adding some doc here and there to explain what happens. Just read it through step by step and you can hopefully understand what happens. Ask questions if anything is unclear.

To use the class posted below do this.

```
$query  = "SELECT ? FROM ?"; // can be any query
$params = array($param1, $param2); //must equal to ammount of "?" in query.
//an error will occur if $param1 or 2 is not of the type string, int, 
//bool or double, it can however be a double like this 2,1 instead of 2.1
$db = new databaseHandler();
$result = $db->runQuery($query, $params);
//or for short runQuery("SELECT * FROM *" , array());
if($result !== false){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result){
        $column1 = $row['columnname'];
        //just do with the result what you want.
    }
}else{
    echo "error occured";
}
```

This is the class that will be able to handle database interactions. Take not that you need to set the connection the way you feel best. You can run all types of queries on this.

```
class databaseHandler{

private $x = ""; //required

//$query = the query, $params = array with params can be empty.
public function runQuery($query, Array $params){
    if($this->checkparams($params, $query)){
        //starts and returns the database connection
        $con = startConnection();    //<--- CHANGE THIS SO IT WORKS FOR YOU
        if($stmt = $con->prepare($query)){
            //obtains type of params if there are any.
            if(count($params) < 0){
                $type = "";
                $i=0;
                foreach($params as $par){
                    $par = $this->checktype($par);
                    $params[$i] = $par;
                    $type = $this->setType($type);
                    if($type === false){
                        echo "type error occured"
                        return false;
                    }
                    $i++;
                }
                //sets $type on the first spot of the array.
                array_unshift($params, $type)
                //binds the params
                call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $this->refValues($params));
            }
            $stmt->execute();
            $result - $stmt->get_result();
            stmt->close();
            return $result; // return the result of the query.
        }else{
            echo "error occured, bad connection";
            return false;
    }else{
        echo "params dont match prepared statement";
        return false;
    }
}

//checks if params are equal to prepared statement requirements.
checkparams($params, $query){
    //counts occurences of ? in query.
    $count = substr_count($q, "?");
    $i = count($params);
    if($count == $i){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

//Checks the type of a param
public function checktype($par){
    $this->x = gettype($par);
    if($this->x == "string"){
        $npar = str_replace(",", ".", $par);
        if(is_numeric($npar)){
            $this->x = "integer";
            if(strpos($npar, ".")){
                $this->x="double";
                return $npar;
            }
        }
    }
    return $par;
}

//sets/adds to the type.
public function setType($type){
    //$this->x from checktype;
    switch($this->x){
        case "string":
        $type = $type."s";
        break;
        case "integer":
        $type = $type."i";
        break;
        case "double":
        $type = $type."d";
        break;
        case "boolean":
        $type = $type."b";
        break;
        case "NULL":
        $type = $type."s";
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return $type; 
}

//This function exist to resolve a few version errors in php.
//not sure what it does exactly, but it resolved some errors I had in the past.               
function refValues($arr){
    if(strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0){
        $refs = array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $value)
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        return $refs;
    }
    return $arr;
}
}
}
```

So pretty much what happens here are a set of checks to execute the query, if anything goes wrong it returns false if nothing goes wrong it returns the result of the query even if the result is empty. It is also possible to not do all of this in a class, though that would make $x global. I think it would be best if you modify certain things so they fit your application best. like the error handling/messages variable names, etc.

The only thing this code doesnt protect you at is errors in your query.

EDIT ---- I DID FIND something this code didnt protect against too, inserting NULL values. I changed this code to make it protect against inserting NULL values, they will be inserted as type string. The database will see its NULL and insert it as NULL value.

just dont try inserting objects or empty values because that would be useless anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing Object Oriented statements with Procedural Statements. This will not work.

Change this statement:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $colval);
```

to this statement:

```
$stmt->bind_result($banner, $bannercode, $location, $status);
```

According to the documentation, `bind_result`:

> This statement binds variables to your prepared statement for result storage.

Therefore, this is where you want `$result` to be defined.

**Note:**  `bind_result` binds one variable ***per*** column. You'll need to add additional variables for each column returned.

You can also simplify this statement:

```
if ($stmt) {
    while ($result = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        array_push($arr, $result);
    }
}
```

to the following:

```
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $arr[] = array($banner, $bannercode, $location, $status);
}
```

No need to check `$stmt` first. The `while` loop will take care of that for you.

The only other thing I would recommend is closing the prepared when you're finished with it. Insert this line:

```
$stmt->close();
```

above your return statement:

```
return $arr;
```

**Reference:**  [Bind Result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Check Example #1 as an additional reference.

Comment: Still getting the warning: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement

Comment: Ah, yes. Apologies. I missed that. You're query is using the `*` wildcard in the SELECT statement. Therefore, you'll need to bind one result variable for each column in your table. (i.e. `$stmt->bind_result(col1, [col2, [col3 etc.]]);`. Or, more appropriately, limit what you're returning in your `select` query to the columns you're going to use.

Comment: I have tried like this now $select = "SELECT banner, bannercode, location, status from advertising WHERE status = ?"; but still viewing the error.

Comment: thanks no worries, standing by, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Ahhh, the problem is that I am not using the function querysp only for this query, I need to use it dynamically that is why I tried something like above. $banner, $bannercode, $location, $status are only available for this query for othery queries will be different values, different columns.

Comment: @Adrian Hmm, that's a whole other scenario. I'll have to think on that one a little. Not sure how to handle immediately.